# Ansatz for solving a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I asked this question ealier today on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/88qr8l/physics_student_ansatz_for_solving_a_differential/) someone told me to better ask this here.

> I started reading about the Klein-Gordon equation and I tried to solve some problems. At some point I had to solve an Differential equation that looked like $f''(r)/f(r) = h(r)$, so I had the idea to use the Ansatz $f(r) = r^a e^{br}$ and define $g(r) = f''(r)/f(r)$. And then I taylored $g$ and $h$ in $s$, neglect everything of order $(r-s)^2$ and higher and solved for $a$ and $b$. Now I have a solution $f(r; a(s), b(s))$ that should solve the differential equation if $r$ is close enough to $s$.
>   Unfortunately that doesn't help. I used this method to solve a problem, that also can be solved analytically ($f'/f = e^x$) and [plotted the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZSqo.jpg) in python to see if this actually works. It doesn't. The reason for it to fail is I think that I get a different solution for every $s$. What I mean by this is that if $F(x;m)$ was an actual solution for every $m$ then $f(x;a(s), b(s)) = F(x;m(s)) \neq F(x;m)|_{m=const.}$.
>   And my question would be if someone knows if this can be fixed and if yes how? Is this maybe a well-known math problem?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest non-trivail ODE of this kind has $h(r)=r$ and is the [equation for the Airy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function). As you can see even in that simple case there are no easy solutions. Some cases are related to other special functions like Bessel-functions, which are themselves solutions of specific second order ODE.